# the usages and the meaning of "at all"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

I didn't get the following sentence straight.

- Excuse me, but can you read at all?

As far as I Know, *at all* used in negative statements to emphasize what you are saying.

This sentence is from a reading article as following:

> Tom is an old farmer. He lives a long way from the town.One day he goes into town to buy something. After shopping, he goes into a
>   restaurant and sits down at a table.When he looks around, he sees
>   some old men put on their eyeglasses before reading their newspapers.
>
> After lunch, he goes to a shop to buy glasses, too. The man in the shop makes him try on a lot of glasses, but Tom always says, "No, I can't read with these."
>
> At last the man asks Tom, "Excuse me, but can you read at all?"
>
> "No, I can't!" Tom says, "If I can read, do you think I will come here to buy glasses?"

My question is: Can the question the man asks Tom be rephrased to:

> "Excuse me, can't you read at all?"

What is the difference between them?

Comment: Side note, shouldn't the sentence "If I can read, do you think I will come here to buy glasses?" be changed to "If I **could** read, do you think I **would** come here to buy glasses?"?

Comment: See a related question on ELU: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52048/negative-questions-vs-positive-questions

Answer (score 4):

The sentence the way it is written is a question which does not imply any commentary on the part of the asker. "Can you read *at all*?" to me merely indicates that who's asking wonders at the ability of reading of the other person. On the contrary, the sentence "**Can't** you read at all?" seems to express surprise, or disappointment; it adds some degree of commentary or judgement on the part of the speaker.

Comment: I agree. I think the asker of "Can you read at all?" maybe expects Tom to say, "Yes, I can read a little bit," (in other words, it's an invitation for Tom to answer by saying how well he can read), whereas the asker of "Can't you read at all?" maybe expects a yes-or-no answer. However, the difference is so subtle that I'd caution against trying to draw a firm distinction between the two; we are truly splitting hairs here. I don't think the narrative would become "wrong" if the question were to be rephrased.

Answer (score 0):

At all means "any amount". So, he's asking if the person has the ability to read any amount - though you would not say "any amount."

He can read a little bit. He can't read at all, not even his name.

Do you like him at all? The skill/ability/affinity is on a scale (from nothing to a lot).  I guess I like him a little.

Can you read at all? and Can't you read at all? mean the same thing with a different nuance or attitude. The second sentence the speaker is expressing surprise that the listener probably cannot read.